# Why does extracting legendary power from Halycon's Ascent fail?

Tags: diablo-iii

I need to extract the legendary power from Halycon's Ascent and it won't let me, it always says "Transmute failed", even though I do have the correct amount of materials.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

The item was enchanted to a socket, could that be the problem?

[image: Screenshot of item]

Comment: Huh.  That should work.  Not sure why that wouldn't.

Comment: Agreed with @Frank, items that have their power extracted are just destroyed, regardless of their enchantment or gems (and you get any sockets gems back upon destruction/extraction just fyi)

Comment: @Orc despite your question regarding specifically the Halcyon's Ascent, would you mind phrasing the title more generically (something like "Why are some legendary power not extractable by Kanai's Cube ?") and use the Halcyons as exemple. It would allow much easier duplicate management in the future

Comment: @WizLiz It ain't my question, but I personally don't mind :-) @DeleteMe?

Comment: stop editing my question in a way that conflicts with my intention. thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Kanai's Cube extracted powers are shared account wide (though there is still a separation between softcore/harcore and season/non season). This leads to some restriction with its usage like : *Only Demon Hunters can slot the effect of an Xbow*.

This also brings 2 majors restrictions in which items can be extracted and which can not :

- If the **orange affix** of a legendary **varies** depending on the class that loot the item (e.g. [The Hellfire Amulet](http://www.diablowiki.net/Hellfire_Amulet) or [The Halcyon's Ascent](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/halcyons-ascent)), then **it can not be extracted**.
- If the **actual effect (i.e. the way it behaves in the game)** of a legendary **changes/destroys the item**, then **it can not be extracted**.

  1. [The Corrupted Ashbringer](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/corrupted-ashbringer) turns your weapon into Ashbringer for a short period of time which is not possible if you have a bow/wand/etc. slotted for weapon, thus making it unextractable.
  2. [Ancestor's Grace](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ancestors-grace) is an amulet that drops only in hardcore mode that allows you to survive one death, in return the amulet is destroyed. This mechanic makes this legendary power unextractable.

Comment: What do you mean with fixed? The effect works on a barb, so I see no reason why I should not be able to extract it

Comment: @DeleteMe I mean that if a monk rolls it, the legendary affix wont be the same. This affix is the dependent on the class you're playing when you loot the Halcyons. The cube only allows to extract legendary from which the orange affix is already known before identifying it. That's just the way it is and I'm affraid there isnt mich you can do unless Bliz decides otherwise. i'd love to extract an Hellfire amulet passive and slot another Hellfire so I get 6 passive but well, I cant =D.

Comment: Interestingly enough the [Haunt of Vaxo](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/haunt-of-vaxo) didn't extract for me either (and others say the same too).

Comment: Haunt of Vaxo extraction was fixed in hotfix 2.3.0a: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/18695103092#4

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a bug with that specific item (Alcyon's ascent). I got two of them, and neither will transmute. They both have the same skill (When you use Archon, you mesmerize...). I'm trying to transmute on my mage, and this is obviously a mage-only power...

Comment: According to the screenshot, it’s not eligible for extraction (filled in diamond of a single colour).  If it were, it’d either be a hollow diamond (yet to be extracted) or a filled in diamond with a bright yellow centre (already extracted)