# Why do some legendary powers not get extracted by Kanai's Cube?

Tags: diablo-iii

I noticed the [Haunt of Vaxo](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/haunt-of-vaxo) legendary power is not extracted by Kanai's cube.  I understand that some powers are not extracted because they vary per character (see answers to [this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233673/why-does-extracting-legendary-power-from-halycons-ascent-fail), which made me think of this one).

Any idea why that and other powers can not be extracted?

Comment: looks like it varrys per character, to me

Comment: I see what you mean though, the legendary affix doesn't vary. The blue effect does, but the orange doesn't.

Comment: @Timelord64 do you mean because the clones would be a the difference characters?  I suppose that is a possibility.

Comment: Im unfamiliar with the new version, but it is an account bound item with a stat determined by the character using it. So if a strength character uses it, it boosts strength, for example. AFAIK this is why blocks the items from being extracted with the cube. I could be way off here, though. I would trust what @Dpeif has to say better

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @Timelord64 actually, the fact that the item is *in any way* character specific, in this case the blue effect, would be my best guess for why they didn't include it in the list of extractables. Kind of an annoying loophole if that is the reason, especially considering how many characters could benefit from the legendary affix.

Comment: I recently started using a Grin Reaper affix in my cube slot, I'm not sure if that is only available to rip for a witch doctor (that's who I use it with), but may be an alternative to the vaxo for you.

Comment: @Dpeif the blue stuff is character specific on ALL items since the Loot 2.0 update, which was before the expansion. If that was the reason why you can't extract the power then you couldn't extract *any* powers.

Comment: @Chippies haha duh, good point. Didn't even think about that, any item (almost always) drops with your characters primary attribute, which can be any of the three shown in your link: strength, intelligence, or dexterity. So it really isn't class specific at all, my bad. No clue why you can't extract it then, maybe the PTR on pc found a way to exploit it that the developers could not abide? I'm console unfortunately, I just got it a few days ago.

Comment: @Adeese, the two questions are similar. However, your suggested duplicate asks "why does this legendary fail" and the answer is "because it is a character-specific legendary". This question asks "why does the legendary fail, **as it is not a character-specific legendary**.

Comment: I think the definitive answer for all such questions is "because it is not in the list of legendaries in the Cube" :-)

Comment: Just wanted to add, they may have put in an update to change this for the Haunt of Vaxo because it can now be extracted.

Answer (score 3):

Kanai's Cube extracted powers are shared account wide (though there is still a separation between softcore/harcore and season/non season). This leads to some restriction with its usage like : *Only Demon Hunters can slot the effect of an Xbow*.

This also brings 2 majors restrictions in which items can be extracted and which can not :

- If the **orange affix** of a legendary **varies** depending on the class that loot the item (e.g. [The Hellfire Amulet](http://www.diablowiki.net/Hellfire_Amulet)), then **it can not be extracted**.
- If the **actual effect (i.e. the way it behaves in the game)** of a legendary **(1) varies** depending on the class that uses it or **(2) is not compatible** with every classes, **it can not be extracted**.

  1. [The Haunt of Vaxo](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/haunt-of-vaxo) will summon clones of your character but those clones depend on which class is wearing the Amulet, thus making the Haunt of Vaxo unextractable.
  2. [The Corrupted Ashbringer](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/corrupted-ashbringer) turns your weapon into Ashbringer for a short period of time which is not possible if you have a bow/wand/etc. slotted for weapon, thus making it unextractable.

Comment: That power could adapt for the character. It almost look like the shadow's character class is fixed which it isn't since you could wear the same Haunt of Vaxo on 2 different classes on your account and the shadows wouldn't be of the class the necklace was found with. Strange they didn't permit its extraction.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Gameplay-wise it doesnt makes much sense to not allow it. However we can't know how this has been programmed and the way it is written right now maybe doesn't allow it or at least not easily. Then this could be patched in a future update.